# Using AngularJS directive in Djangon

Tags: django, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Django, and want to integrate AngularJS with Django. Djangular is installed and can be used.

The basic directory structure is follows:

`mysite/app/Templates/app/index.html`

`mysite/app/Templates/app/directives/item-detail.html`

The `index.html` is referred to in `url.py` by `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),`, and in the `views.py`, `index()` returns

```
return render(
    request,
    'app/index.html',
    {
        'somevar': "some variables from index()"
    }
)
```

So when I define a `directive` `<item-detail>` using

```
app.directive('itemDetail', function(){
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: ''
})
```

I wonder what to put in the `templateUrl` (or there should be other configuration)? `templateUrl: "directives/item-detail.html"` gives a `404` error; `template: "<h1>This is a template</h1>"` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat Angular templates as static files. They don't need to be parsed by Django, and you don't want to have to create urls for them. Put them in the static directory and refer to them via the normal static paths.